# UserLogin Object field in Reports

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, reports-api

I need to add some fields IsFrozen, Unfroze date which are present in the UserLogin Object in a custom report type. But unable to do it so far. Also, I read that the IsFrozen field cannot be included in a report and is only available through Web Service API. Want to know if there is any way to include them in the report type.

Comment: This is not supported at the minute, unfortunately. Does the customer require an actual report or just the data in a certain format? Could you query the data on the userLogin object and export as csv?

Comment: It has to be an actual report on which they need to work on later. And Yes, I can export it as CSV but the customer don't want to depend on us every time they require the list which happens very frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it is a know limitation. IsFrozen, Unfroze date cannot be included in the report.